# Is ear piercing permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, women, men, adornments

> Islam doesn't allow to change the features created by Allah like
>   removing the face hairs, creating a space between tooth artificially
>   to look beautiful.- [Bhukhari](http://hadithcollection.com/sahihbukhari/105-Sahih%20Bukhari%20Book%2072.%20Dress/6864-sahih-bukhari-volume-007-book-072-hadith-number-815.html)

I have some questions under this piercing topic:

- Is it allowed to pierce ear for wearing jewellery?  Is it considered as changing the feature created by Allah(subh)?
- If ear piercing allowed, what is the rule for men and ear piercing?
- Did any of the prophet's wives wear earrings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wearing of earrings for girls/women is okay, as there are narration of the women companions doing so:

> ثُمَّ أَتَى النِّسَاءَ فَوَعَظَهُنَّ وَذَكَّرَهُنَّ وَأَمَرَهُنَّ
> بِالصَّدَقَةِ، فَرَأَيْتُهُنَّ يَهْوِينَ إِلَى آذَانِهِنَّ
> وَحُلُوقِهِنَّ يَدْفَعْنَ إِلَى بِلاَلٍ، ثُمَّ ارْتَفَعَ هُوَ
> وَبِلاَلٌ إِلَى بَيْتِهِ
>
> Then the Prophet (ﷺ) went to the women and instructed them and gave
> them religious advice and ordered them to give alms and I saw them
> reaching out (their hands to) their ears and necks (to take off the
> earrings and necklaces, etc.) and throwing (it) towards Bilal. Then
> the Prophet (ﷺ) returned with Bilal to his house .

[صحيح بخاري (Bukari)](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/67/182)

And there are other narrations.  It is regarded as an okay decoration for women.  And of course this is for women/girls and not for boys or men.  As for your third question, whether any of the Prophet's (ﷺ) wives wore earrings, it is narrated that Safiyyah (May Allah be pleased with her) had gold earnings, and she gave it to Fatimah and some other women with her.

Sources: [حكم ثقب أذن الأنثى للحلى](http://islamqa.info/ar/78255)  ، [ثقب أذن الصبي](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/56739)، [حكم ثقب الأذنين للزينة](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/126559)

Comment: How can we say if some of the companions worn ear rings then Islam permits ear piercing, they might pierced their ear before accepting Islam. My first part of the question is, what does islam say about piercing ear for wearing jwels.

Answer (score -1):

there is an ayat that prohibits that: 4:119 : http://quran.com/4/116-122 :

They call upon instead of Him none but female [deities], and they [actually] call upon none but a rebellious Satan. Whom Allah has cursed. For he had said, "I will surely take from among Your servants a specific portion. And I will mislead them, and I will arouse in them [sinful] desires, and I will command them so they will slit the ears of cattle, and I will command them so they will change the creation of Allah ." And whoever takes Satan as an ally instead of Allah has certainly sustained a clear loss.

i think if quran contradicts hadith, quran wins. so, there is hadith, shown in answer of mujahid, that shows that prophet said nothing to disallow piercing while dealed with usage of earrings, but, i think, it should not be used to think that it is ok to pierce body, because, as you see, allah said that it is idea given by satan. i think, maybe, they, the women, in time of muhammad, refuced to pierce their daughters and used only already made holes in ears, maybe, they attached earrings somehow without piercing. another story, about abu zar, http://sunnah.com/search/?q=eleven+women , also can be interpreted so it is not used to allow piercing. (maybe it was so clear to everybody from quran that piercing is bad, that muhammad did not say about that, as the main topic of story and of muhammad's answer is another, not about piercing).